# AWS + Github Auto-deploy: hooks does not work

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, aws-code-deploy, autodeploy

I'm playing with AWS Code Deploy and want to setup automatically building environment.
What I've done:

```
1. Configured `Code Deploy` for my GitHub repository. (it deploys fine)
2. Added AWS Code Deploy service in Github settings of my repo.
3. Added Github Auto-Deployment service in Github of my repo.
```

I was also following this documentation:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/automatically-deploy-from-github-using-aws-codedeploy/

But after adding some commit into my `master` branch, there is no auto deployments on my CodeDeploy Deployments section...

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This guide helps:

http://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2016-12-26-autodeploy-from-github-using-aws-codedeploy/

There were some minor issues with hooks configuration.